# Informix database connection in Play framework

Tags: playframework, informix

I want to connect Informix and Play framework but I have a problem. My `application.conf` contains the following code:

```
db.default.driver = com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
db.default.url = "jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/test:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_ids_1150_1"
db.default.user = "informix"
db.default.password = "123456"
```

and the error is :

```
Driver not found : [ com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver ]
```

and my `build.sbt` file is like this:

```
name := "percobaan"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.informix"%"informix"%"ifxjdbc"
)    

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

What might be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears if your JDBC-driver was not found. It means you have to add the driver somehow to your project. Usually by either adding a jar-file containing the driver to your lib-folder or by adding a dependency to your build-file (usually build.sbt).

Make sure that either the jar-file containing the driver is in your lib-folder or the appropriate dependency has been added to the build.sbt-file.

*[edit]* I did a bit further research for you and it is probably the best solution to copy the jar-file containing the driver into the lib-directory.
Have a look at the documentation of Play, regarding unmanaged dependencies: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies

Comment: I 've added " com.informix " % " informix " % " ifxjdbc " , but I get a new problem

Comment: so how should I write in built.sbt ?

Comment: like this "name := "percobaan"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.informix"%"informix"%"IfxDriver"
)    

play.Project.playJavaSettings"

Comment: Is there an error message? You probably need to add a resolver as well, so SBT knows how to resolve the dependency.

Comment: this the error message : com.informix#informix;IfxDriver: not found

Comment: I did some more research for you. Try adding the jar file to the lib-folder. (I updated my answer, have a look at the link)

Comment: Have you downloaded the driver-jar and put it in the lib-folder? Does this work for you?

Comment: where the lib directory?

Comment: If the lib-diectory does no exist, you have to create it. Read this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies

Comment: i already read that , but i don't know to create the informix driver lib

Comment: Just create a directory called "lib" in your play-project-directory (where the build.sbt file is) and copy the jar file into this directory. Remove `"com.informix"%"informix"%"ifxjdbc"` from your build.sbt-file and then run `sbt clean` and `sbt run` and it should work. SBT will automatically include all the jar-files from the lib-directory.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Peanut , The Problem was Solved ^_^